# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python-3.x

```
products['sentiment'] = products['rating'].apply(lambda rating : +1 if rating > 3 else -1)
```

It is showing the same error everytime:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'apply'

I am using python 3.7, could you please help to resolve this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: That 1st line is the code,what else i should mention ? i clearly wrote about the issue i'm facing.Please help!

Comment: @psygo the code you provided is not enough. We have no idea what products is, is it a dictionnary? a pandas DataFrame ? etc...

Comment: @LucBlassel it is a numpy 2D-array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `products['rating']` is a `float`; try this instead:

```
prodcuts['sentiment'] = 1 if products['rating'] > 3 else -1
```